# How can I sync Emacs with Google Calendar and Contacts?

Tags: emacs, sync, google-calendar, google-contacts

Is there a way to use Emacs to sync with Google Calendar and Google Contacts, ideally keeping a local copy so I can access them offline?

Comment: Why? What? What can emacs do with that information?

Comment: I just like to see if I can use/manage my Google Calendar and Contacts in Emacs as part of an attempt to consolidate my work into one, free and open source, package.

Comment: [Also asked at Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1850).

Comment: @Nifle "What can emacs do with that information?" What part of calendar and contact syncing is odd? you can use emacs as a diary/agenda and a mail client. Why wouldn't you want your calendar and contacts to sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GoogleClient) mentions [emacs-g-client](http://emacspeak.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/lisp/g-client/) for access to Google calendar. It was [written in 2007](http://emacspeak.blogspot.com/2007/03/emacs-client-for-google-services.html), which is old by web service standards, so it may or may not still work.

Comment: Just checked their discussion group, last post in 2009. Will try it, tough. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you use BBDB to store your contacts in Emacs, then you should take a look at [ASynK](http://karra-asynk.appspot.com) :

> ASynK is the only software today that can do bi-directional sync
>   between bbdb and google. In fact even Outlook (on Windows) and CardDAV
>   are supported by ASynK. i.e. you can sync your BBDB to outlook, to an
>   ownCloud installation or to Google - it's all bidirectional.
>
> Calendar sync is not supported yet, but the basic sync infrastructure
>   is in place. So it may happen some day.

(Disclaimer : I am the author.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't imagine there's a good answer on the calendar side of things.  Impedance mismatch between Diary and other stuff.

On the contacts side of things, there's *some* work done on BBDB-to/from-vCard.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BbdbExportImportSync describes some of it.

The seemingly most complete import/export is trebb/bbdb-vcard at GitHub.  Again, there still seems to be some mismatch, so I'd mostly be inclined to manage the data in one place, whether that be BBDB or Google Contacts, and shove from the authoritative source to other places.

Answer (score 0):

Org mode with [org-caldav](https://github.com/dengste/org-caldav) will sync your agenda with any caldav server. And google offer one such a server